# What do 总 and 不时 mean here together?

Tags: meaning

他说，当公司总经理从他身旁经过时，总会不时地赞美他“你扫的地真干净“。

It seems I have 总 ‘always‘ and 不时 ‘occasionally' or 'often' together.

Does the 总经理 always or occasionally laud said sweeper? Or is it 'on all occasions'??

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider **总会** together:

**ABC**

> be bound to; be inevitable; be sure to happen

总会 + 不时 = be sure to + often = he is bound to frequently.../he is sure to often...

ABC calls 总会, here, a:

**Verb Phrase**

> Dòngcí Cízǔ 动词词组
>
> This includes
>
> (i) descriptive predicates that do not behave as stative verbs, e.g., ǎirán ‘amicable; amiable’, as well as
>
> (ii) phrases and longer chunks containing a verb that are not fixed expressions, e.g., bǎiláibǎiqù ‘sway; waver’, áidào tiānhēi ‘bear up until nightfall’.

Comment: Thanks. However, I would never write 'he is bound to frequently'. How about just 'He often praises him'

Comment: In English we could say "He is sure to praise him often/frequently."

Answer (score 0):

Question 5 was: 清洁工为什么要和小偷搏斗？ Answer C: 公司经理经常夸奖他。

总会不时 = 经常。

Comment: No, `总会不时` != `经常`.

Comment: 就是什么？你能提个建议吗？谢谢！

Comment: Have you seen @user3306356's answer?

Comment: Yes, I read it. It says 'He is sure to often'.  This is not good English because of the opposing meanings of 'sure to' and 'often'. Maybe this makes sense in Chinese, but not in English. Recently I had a similar use of opposing meanings with '力量薄弱‘。 Maybe this is a Chinese thing which cannot be put into English.

Comment: Sorry my English is not good, but `总会不时` really makes sense in Chinese. For your example, the manager may meet the cleaner five times every month, and he may praise only once among them, so it is `不时`. But he keeps this kind of action for many months, so it is `总会`. BTW: `力量薄弱` does not have opposing meanings, it just means `strenth/power` is insufficient. Maybe you think `力量` means `powerful`, but it just means `strenth/power`, while `有力量/力量大` means `powerful`.

Comment: Your English is OK, better than my Chinese! What I had was 自主研发力量的薄弱，在某种程度上制约着民族游戏产业的发展。I did not find any dictionaries which say 薄弱 = insufficient. I therefore think 研发力量的薄弱= R&D strength 的 weakness.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. So, there's not opposing meanings?

Comment: No, such a collocation is not English, because we cannot write 'strong weakness'. Something is weak, or strong, it cannot be strong and weak. This must be a cultural difference, just like '总会不时‘ 'always will sometimes'. It is a bit like saying 'cold heat', not good English. Can you say that in Chinese?

Comment: `冷中热`?`热中冷`? Anyway, I can understand it, but maybe hard to pick a perfectly suitable Chinese word for it. Yes, it's the difficulty and fun of translation.

Comment: Albert Einstein, when he was a student, attended a lecture. The professor was talking about good and evil. Einstein said, maybe there is no good and evil. There is in fact no hot and cold, what we call cold is just less heat, until we reach absolute zero, where molecules stop moving. Einstein said, perhaps evil is like this, that is less of  'good'.

Comment: @Pedroski But it's not "strong weakness", it should be "weakness' strength" or "strength of weakness", since there's a 的, which makes sense, whatever metaphor it's supposed to mean.

Comment: Haha, even if you view it as a possessive, it makes no sense in English.
Independent R&D strength's weakness. You can change it thus: 薄弱的自主研发力量。 Would you then say it is 'Weakness's independent R&D strength' ? I think not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't like the Chinese sentence in your question, because I consider it poorly organized. It sounds to me like being said by a janitor who didn't receive much education.

If you translate "总是" into "always", I'm sure you'll get confused. If you translate "总是" into "regularly" or "usually", it reduces the confusion.

Chinese are likely to overuse the word "总是"。For example, in the last month, Xiao Zhang was late for work for 16 days out of the 22 work days.  Then his boss may complain:

最近小张总是迟到。

We all know there were at least 8 days that Xiao Zhang came to work on time.  So logically "总是" is not appropriately used in this scenario. However, most Chinese native speakers speak this way, and it is one of the language habits that confuse Chinese learners.

Hopefully my post doesn't cause more confusion.

Comment: 谢谢，只是没有‘总是’有‘总会’